# How to avoid exponential notation when concatenating 2 Pandas string columns

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe

```
$ dfoffers.head(1)    

              FVID  vnum   
0  1000373197012497808     2  

$ dfoffers.dtypes
$ 
FVID      int64
vnum      int64
dtype: object
```

The goal is to concatenate the long string in fVID and the short string in vnum into a new column.

I do this:

```
dfoffers['FVID'] = dfoffers['FVID'].astype(str) 
dfoffers['vnum'] = dfoffers['vnum'].astype(str) 
dfoffers['combo'] = df.FVID.astype(str).str.cat(df.vnum.astype(str), sep='')
dfoffers['combo'] = dfoffers['combo'].astype(str)
```

and much to my surprise the result is this:

```
$ dfoffers.head(1) 

              FVID      vnum                combo
0  1000373197012497808    2    1.0003415817309268e+181.0
```

How to get it just to add the literal '2' to the end of the long FVID and display the new string without exponential notation?

Comment: Your code works well on my side

Comment: What's the dtype of FVID?  I'm pretty sure it's float based on your result. 
 So what's happening here is that you're simply getting the float representation when you convert to str.  You could solve by converting to int or rounding *before* doing the string concat, altho the conversion to int will probably result in loss of precision (or something to that effect).  But the concatenation will work as expected at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
dfoffers['combo'] = dfoffers['FVID'].map(str) + dfoffers['vnum']
```